# uitoolbar location changes according to different iPhone SDKs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolbar at the bottom of the view. when I run the application using iPhone Simulator 2.2.1, the toolbar is displayed in place. But when I run the application using iPhone Simulator 3.0 the toolbar is shifted up from its place. Is there any way I can fix this ? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using toolbars in iPhone OS 2.x is hard to get it right. The documentation is fuzzy, or non-existing. The addition of proper toolbar handling in iPhone OS 3.0 is a clear sign of Apple admitting that toolbars in 2.x where just not ready for the public.

This is not the answer you expect, but the answer you need. Ask yourself; *"Will a user who has not bothered to update to iPhone OS 3.0 bother to install my app?"*

The answer is most probably no.

Then what you should do is make sure your application uses a `UINavigationController`, and have each `UIViewController` that needs a toolbar set it's `toolbarItems` property to an `NSArray` with the `UIBarButtonItem` objects you need.

On iPhone OS 3.0 this will result in a toolbar that is automatically populated, laid out, and managed for you with no fuzz.

Answer (score 0):

What does it look like on the device?

I've had wonky issues with the 2.2.1 simulator since updating to the 3.0 SDK, and from what I've found on Google, I'm not the only one. If it looks fine on the device, then ignore the simulator issues, or debug with the 3.0 simulator instead.